# PHP Socket server freezes after many request

Tags: php, sockets, http

I am writing HTTP Server using PHP sockets and currently it works normally but the problem appears then I am running apache benchmark with 25 level concurrency and 1000 request it just freezes and timeouts, but with 24 concurrency level it works perfectly fine. Maybe someone will figure out a flaw in my architecture because I don't think that concurrency here is a problem because kernel should balance everything.

Here is my minimal reproducible code:

```
<?php


$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($server, '127.0.0.1', '9090');
socket_set_nonblock($server);
socket_listen($server);

$selectSockets = [$server];
$null = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid > 0) {

    } else {
        while (true) {
            $result = @socket_accept($server);

            if (false === $result) {
                $errCode = socket_last_error($server);
                if (0 !== $errCode) {
                    throw new Exception(socket_strerror($errCode));
                }
            } else {
                $readSockets = [$result];
                $buffer = '';
                $requestFinished = false;
                while (!$requestFinished) {
                    $count = @socket_select($readSockets, $null, $readSockets, 2);

                    if ($count) {
                        $read = socket_read($result, 4096);

                        if ($read === '0' || $read) {
                            $requestFinished = true;
                        } else {
                            $buffer .= $read;
                        }
                    }
                }

                socket_write($result, 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' . "\r\n\r\n" . 'Hello World');
                socket_close($result);
            }


            @socket_select($selectSockets, $null, $null, 10);
        }
    }
}

pcntl_wait($status);
```

Command I use to test:

```
ab -c 25 -n 1000 http://127.0.0.1:9090/
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that specific issue. However, it happens when you run it multiple times and the overall request count is increased thereby.

Comment: Increace -c if you  cant reproduce it it depends on system somehow... Now I even able to test with 30 but then I increase more it fails.

Comment: `ab -c 500 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1:9090/` works perfectly fine here, at least the first time. The second time it freezes after `9946` requests.

Comment: Sorry wrongly understood last sentence. I cant see any way how overall request count could impact this code becase there is no storing or something happening here...